# Selenium webdriver to load comments from status/photo on facebook timeline

Tags: python, facebook, selenium

I am using `Selenium Webdriver` in Python for an application which automates the use of Facebook. I am struggling to find a way to select to load comments (which appear as a little speech bubble and number to represent the number of comments) on objects on my timeline whether it be a photo or a status.

When looking at the source they all contain similar HTML to this one :

```
<a aria-label="Show comments" class="mls UFIBlingBoxTimelineItem" data-ft="  
{&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;O&quot;}" data-hover="tooltip" data-tooltip-alignh="right"
href="#"data-reactid=".2p.1" id="js_4">
   <span data-reactid=".2p.1.0">
       <i class="UFIBlingBoxTimelineCommentIcon UFIBlingBoxSprite" 
       datareactid=".2p.1.0.0">
            </i><span class="UFIBlingBoxText" data-reactid=".2p.1.0.1">5</span></span> 
            </a>
```

But trying the `id`, `XPATH`, `class name` to find the element all do not work....any ideas?

EDIT

html for comment once loaded

```
<span data-   
reactid=".cb.1:3:1:$comment699251410106274_2091272:0.0.$right.0.$left.0.0.0:$comment-
body.0"><span data-
reactid=".cb.1:3:1:$comment699251410106274_2091272:0.0.$right.0.$left.0.0.0:$comment-
body.0.$end:0:$0:0">Anto, you are not funny honey! </span></span>
```

Comment: Please provide the exact HTML where the comments appears

Comment: the text of the comments doesnt appear to be in the html...before clicking the comments button to show them all that is in the html for them is what is in my first post and once clicked to show comment each comment has html looking like this

Comment: Isn't "Anto, you are not funny honey!" the comment?? Is it what you are trying to select?? Have to tried waiting for it to load??

Comment: no im not looking for a comment in particular that was just an example....to get the comments for anything on your facebook wall you need to click the comments icon underneath the object...i want a way to click the button to show the comments

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes an element can be 'not visible' to the webdriver even though it's visible to the user.  This usually involves a page with javascript changing elements with fancy html overlays (I'm forgetting the exact word).

Try

```
driver.execute_script( "return $('a.html');" )
```

Then implement the click with js/jq

Comment: thanks for the advice sounds like a good idea...ill let you know how it goes

Comment: sorry could i ask for a bit more help when ive added that code in i get this error message....... Message: u'<![EX[["Tried to get element with id of \\"%s\\" but it is not present on the page.","a.html"]]]>' ; Stacktrace:......just wondering if you had any advice...ive searched the web ttrying to find javscript to do the task but havent got it working yet

Comment: "a.html" was just my dummy example, it looks like you should use "a.mls.UFIBlingBoxTimelineItem". Take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: ahhh ye i see ive tried that and get the error.... Message: u'<![EX[["Tried to get element with id of \\"%s\\" but it is not present on the page.","a.mls.UFIBlingBoxTimelineItem"]]]>' ;